# Which Recommendation Algorithm for Sending Offers to Clients?

Tags: recommender-system

We are trying to identify which offers to send to our clients through email.  Suppose we have offers with the following data:

Offers:
[
    {       id: 1,
        countriesVisited: {
            France: 2
            Italy: 34
            Germany: 7
        },
        tourQualities: {
            First-class: 12,
            Economy: 31
        }
    }, 
    {       id: 2,
        countriesVisited: {
            Italy: 6
            Germany: 5,
            Greece: 10
        },
        tourQualities: {
            First-class: 8,
            Economy: 13
        }
    }
]

Clients: {
    {
        id: 100,
        countriesRequested: {
            Italy: 3,
            France: 4
        },
        tourQualities: {
            Economy: 7
        }
    }
}

We want to identify which offers to show to the client based on their requests.  How would we try to break this problem down?  This seems like a common recommendation/weighted set problem, but don’t know what steps/algorithms to take to solve such a problem.

Comment: How many clients do you have? Keep in mind that just sending a list of the most popular places is already a very good baseline (you can exclude places the client has already been to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to approach this, if you wanted to build a personal recommendation system. Remember though, as a user already mentioned, recommending to most popular trips is probably a pretty good place to start.

1. Use Market Basket Analysis:

You're in a unique situation, because your clients are taking trips to multiple locations when they make one purchase. In most scenarios, the user is choosing one product, be that a movie, song, or food item.

What you could do is use a market basket analysis to identify which countries your clients like to go to during a single trip and how they prefer to travel, and then build a weighted score based a metric list the confidence or lift.

This might be a little biased since you are building the package for them, and they select from your options, but it's still a method.

2. Use implicit ratings

This is how I built the recommendation system my company uses. Unlike some other companies, we don't capture enough ratings of our product to build a good model. Instead, I use implicit ratings; this yielded a sparse data frame. If a user purchased a specific product, it was flagged with a 1, otherwise it was a 0.

You can use this to build a collaborative filtering algorithm that will give you  some recommended locations. The recommendations would be isolated to just a specific location and tour quality, so you would most likely have to build some type of score to rank the options.

I'm not sure what language you're using, but there's a great package for Python called [Implicit](https://github.com/benfred/implicit). You can use this to build a collaboertive filtering algorithm, and it's easy to run in parallel if you have a lot of data.

Best of luck!